# Upgrading hardware in a Dell Optiplex GX280

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, power-supply, power-consumption

I have a Dell Optiplex GX280 which has a 250 Watt PSU.

It currently has 512 MB RAM, built-in graphics chip and a 40 GB HDD.

I am thinking of upgrading the RAM to 4 GB, the HDD to 250 GB, and adding a GPU to the PCI Express x16 slot which has the bus type 1.0a and it's a half height slot, not to sure what that means.

I understand which RAM and HDD I need to get, but I am not confident enough to get a GPU yet.

Will I need one of these low profile cards?

[LINK](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?sq=120&q=pci%2Bexpress%2Bgraphics%2Bcard&sq=low%2Bprofile&filtercat=215&sort=pricelow&limit=10&page=1&subsearch=Go)

Plus, those cards don't say if they are for the 120 pin PCI Express interface, or if they are for the 240 pin interface. Am I correct to say that a full length PCI Express interface is 240 pin and a half height version is 120 pin?

Also, if I do go through this upgrade, do I have enough wattage to power all this?

Comment: Half-height refers to the amount of physical space in the case.  Cards come in 2 types - full height (about 4 inches hight) and half height (about 2 inches or so).  It sounds like you'll need the smaller version.  This has no reference to the bus type - all bus types come in full or half height varients.

Comment: Also, looking at the pictures there's only one on that list that isn't x16 (judging by the size of the connector on the card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a low profile card (they're "half height")

To confirm if a card is x16 or not just google the manufacturer part number, find the manufacturer's site, and read the specifications.  For example, the first on the list:

http://www.zotacusa.com/geforce-8400-gs-lp-512mb-64-bit-gddr2-567mhz-667mhz-zt-84meh4m-hsl.html

In "specification" it says "Interface: PCI Express x16"